# Create or Update with Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Im making a site where users can post and read each others posts. 
I want to make it possible for all users to mark the posts they have read, thus showing only posts which are not read. It should also be possible to undo this. So I have a model and table for both Users and Posts.

The way I thought of doing it was creating a PostsRead table which would contain the unique id for the user and for the post. Then I could fetch all the posts and remove the ones from the PostsRead table. So the question(s) is:

1) Is this a good (best practice-ish) way to do it?

2) How? I guess I need to check if there is a record in the PostsRead-table containing the user_id/post_id pair. If it is not, insert a new row. And if it is, I guess I need to update the current row. It should maybe have a boolean field telling if the post is read or not. How would the code for this be?

When I go through it in my head, this approach seems....weird. Am I on the wrong track here? I hope the question was understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the best practice to do it this way.

Create a table called 'user_read' with 'user_id' and 'post_id' (both as primary key)

```
Schema::create('user_read', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->primary(['user_id', 'post_id']);
});
```

To set it up you should have this relation in your model.

User.php

```
public function reads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'user_read', 'user_id', 'post_id')
           ->withTimestamps();
}
```

To store a new post that the user read you can just do

```
//1 and 3 are the posts ids
$user->reads()->sync([1, 3]);
```